# DI - register all implementation of derived class by generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following:

```
public interface IModelProcessor<S>
    where S : MyAbstractClass
{
    void ProcessModel(S myAbstractClass);
}

public abstract class ModelProcessor<S> : IModelProcessor<S>
    where S : MyAbstractClass
{
    public void ProcessModel(S myAbstractClass)
    {
        // Implementation here.
    }
}

// ConcreteOne derives from MyAbstractClass.
public class ConcreteOneProcessor : ModelProcessor<ConcreteOne> 
{
}
    
// ConcreteTwo derives from MyAbstractClass.
public class ConcreteTwoProcessor : ModelProcessor<ConcreteTwo>
{
}
    
// ConcreteThree derives from MyAbstractClass.
public class ConcreteThreeProcessor : ModelProcessor<ConcreteThree>
{
}


public class ModelProcessorFactory : IModelProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IModelProcessor<MyAbstractClass>> _modelProcessors;

    public ModelProcessorFactory(
        IEnumerable<IModelProcessor<MyAbstractClass>> modelProcessors)
    {
        _modelProcessors = modelProcessors; // Always null.
    }
}
```

I want to be able to register all implementations of IModelProcessor so thay are injected into the ModelProcessorFactory above, but the collection is always null at runtime.

I have tried:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelProcessor<ConcreteOne>, ConcreteOneProcessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelProcessor<ConcreteTwo>, ConcreteTwoProcessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelProcessor<ConcreteThree>, ConcreteThreeProcessor>();
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: And for example `ConcreteOneProcessor` **is not** an `IModelProcessor<MyAbstractClass>` . It **is** a `ModelProcessor<ConcreteOne>` and therefore _implements_ `IModelProcessor<ConcreteOne>` but **not** `IModelProcessor<MyAbstractClass>`.

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Answer (score 0):

You can register it by using the below extension method:

```
public static class DependencyExtensions 
{
     public static IServiceCollection AddGenericInterface(this IServiceCollection services,Type interfaceType, Assembly assembly)
     {
        foreach (var exportedType in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
        {  
          if (exportedType.IsClass && !exportedType.IsAbstract )
           {
              var interfaces =  exportedType.GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType);

              // If you need to support multiple interface for the same class 
              foreach (var typeDefinition in interfaces.ToList())
              {
                services.AddScoped(typeDefinition, exportedType);
              }
            }
         }

        return services;
      }
 }
```

And then add it to you services like the below:

```
Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
```